# How to embed a view in hook_page_build()

Tags: 7, views, hooks

I'm trying to render a view into a region in **hook_page_build()**.  I'm using views_embed_view(), but I'm getting the errors:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in element_children()
>   (line 6428 of /var/www/.../includes/common.inc). Warning: Illegal
>   string offset '#children' in drupal_render() (line 5893 of
>   /var/www/.../includes/common.inc). Warning: Illegal string offset
>   '#children' in drupal_render() (line 5903 of
>   /var/www/.../includes/common.inc). Warning: Illegal string offset
>   '#children' in drupal_render() (line 5941 of
>   /var/www/.../includes/common.inc). Warning: Illegal string offset
>   '#printed' in drupal_render() (line 5948 of
>   /var/www/.../includes/common.inc).

I have a view named 'blogs' and a view named 'block_2'.  In my hook:

```
function mymod_page_build(&$page) {
    $page['sidebar_second']['blogs'] = views_embed_view('blogs', 'block_2');
}
```

I'm trying to move away from blocks and context, and just render content I'd otherwise use in blocks directly into their regions in **hook_page_build()**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs say [hook_page_build()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7)'s $page variable is for [render arrays](https://www.drupal.org/node/930760).

Less obvious from the docs without digging a little further but [views_embed_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7) returns a string of HTML markup.

So just assigning the result of views_embed_view() to the render array breaks it.

Instead you can use a [#markup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup) element.

Because it is the default element type you don't have to specify an element type or theme function or anything, so you can just do this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_build().
 */
function MODULENAME_page_build(&$page) {
  $page['sidebar_second']['blogs']['#markup'] = views_embed_view('blogs', 'block_2');
}
```

If that is your entire code for this though (if you don't have some complex logic relating to when this view is being added) I would not recommend adding a block to a region in this manner.

There are lots of options already out there for adding blocs to regions without custom code. For example you could use one of these:

- [Drupal core block module](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/block)
- [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context)
- [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels)